# Add distance between multiple series in 3d MS chart Winforms having more than 1000 datapoints

Tags: winforms, mschart

I have scenario where i have 2 or more series and single chart area( 3D style).
When im adding more than 1000 data points for both the series, Im not able to the see the distance between both the series data points.
Note: I tried with Point width for Series, adding Border thickness and color also, but the entire grid squeezes.

In this Image, it has 1000 Data Points for both the series looks squeezed/overlapped , i need to have distance between points from different series:
[image]

This Image has 100 points for both the series, it shows some space between data points between series:
[image]

Comment: It looks squished because your y-axis goes to 2000 when the highest value is only 1000.  Change the max on your y-axis to be like 1010, it should give a better view of the data.

Comment: @Baddack : Thanks for the suggestion. but still it looks the same. My requirement is there should be some white space between series points , as it is shown in the first image(as there is blue and orange colors given for 2 series ,and user can easily differentiate between both). that gets lost when i add populate more than 100 data points

Answer (score 0):

You can improve the result by setting [`Area3DStyle.PointDepth`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chartarea3dstyle.pointdepth(v=vs.110).aspx) and/or [`Area3DStyle.PointGapDepth`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chartarea3dstyle.pointgapdepth(v=vs.110).aspx).

Both are limited to `1000` percent..:

> The unit of measurement is expressed as a percentage of the distance
>   between data points in one row.

Therefore, the more points you have, the closer the series are squeezed together. You can make the value(s) depend on the point count, but when you have too many points it will still get that flat look..

But for 2000 points you can get away with this:

[image]

[image]

I used this code:

```
ChartArea ca = chart.ChartAreas[0];
int depth = Math.Min(1000, pointCount);
ca.Area3DStyle.PointDepth = depth;
ca.Area3DStyle.PointGapDepth = depth;
```